# Send javascript variables to spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to develop simple application using spring mvc and I need to pass javascript parameters to spring controller. I have tried several methods and none of them were worked. Following is my javascript and spring controller. Please help me to sort this issue.

Java script

```
function searchViaAjax(id) {
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "search/api/getSearchResult",
        data : JSON.stringify(id),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(id) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", id);
            display(id);
            alert(response);   
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
}
```

AjaxController.java

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult")

    public String getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id) {
        System.out.println("come to ajax"+ id);
        return "hello";

    }
}
```

Comment: `data : JSON.stringify({ id: id }),`

Comment: I tried in this way. But didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass json as requestbody then above call is applicable. To send request param you have to as below:

Use following ajax call:

```
function searchViaAjax(id) {
var tempId = id;
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/search/api/getSearchResult",
    data : {id:tempId},
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(id) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", id);
        display(id);
        alert(response);   
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        display(e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
}
```

also you can acheive this using get method as below:

```
 function searchViaAjax(id) { 
 $.ajax({ 
 type : "GET", 
 url : "/search/api/getSearchResult/"+id, 
 timeout : 100000, 
 success : function(id) { 
 console.log("SUCCESS: ", id); 
 display(id); 
 alert(response); 
}, 
error : function(e) { 
console.log("ERROR: ", e); 
display(e); 
}, 
done : function(e) { 
console.log("DONE"); 
} 
}); 
} 

@Controller 
public class AjaxController { 

@ResponseBody 
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult/{id}") 
public String getSearchResultViaAjax(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) 
{ 
 return String.valueOf(id); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this didn't work for me.

Comment: change url to  url : "/search/api/getSearchResult",

Comment: and it returns hello as response not id as you returned "hello" string

Comment: '/' in start should add as it append this path to context path of application

Comment: I have checked and it is not working for me. It is really simple issue,but i have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: is your webpage which have javascript call generated from same server?

Comment: yes. it is.The id is passing to java script from jsp without an issue.

Comment: get contextpath in one variable like  var env = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"; and then append url to this in call  url :env + "/search/api/getSearchResult" this might work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152428/discussion-between-devram-kandhare-and-dmaprasad).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `JSON.stringify`, you are actually sending a JSON object to your spring controller's method. All you have to do is wrap your json object as a java object like so.

```
public class UserId {

    private int id;

    // setters and getters

}
```

And in your controller's method use `@RequestBody` to map your `JSON` to your `UserId` class like so

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody UserId user) {
    System.out.println("come to ajax" + user.getId());
    return "hello";
}
```

**PS:** Haven't tested it but should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a post request you are making from your ajax to controller.
You are missing "methodType=RequestMethod.POST" on your spring controller.

Replace `@RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult")` with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult", methodType=RequestMethod.POST)
```