# How to send value from jsp page to database without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a spring+hibernate webapp for practicing translation skill from Russian to English.
In one of my jsp pages I am retrieving all the questions from database and placing them into a table with the following columns: text in Russian, field for user's translation, button for checking the result. 
**The goal is to save user's input into database without refreshing the page**. How can I do it?
I tried several options, but none of them worked for me.
I used the solution from [Send javascript variables to spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791117/send-javascript-variables-to-spring-controller) in my project, but nothing happened at all.
Part of "firstPage.jsp" ("/first" path in the controller):

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
            function searchViaAjax(id) {
                var tempId = id;
                alert("Start");
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "./search/api/getSearchResult",
                    data : {id:tempId},
                    timeout : 100000,
                    success : function(id) {
                        alert("success");
                        console.log("SUCCESS: ", id);
                        display(id);
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        alert("error");
                        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                        display(e);
                    },
                    done : function(e) {
                        alert("done");
                        console.log("DONE");
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="searchViaAjax(1)">Simple button</button>
</body>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping("/first")
    public String getFirst(){
        return "firstPage";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
        System.out.println("come to ajax"+ id);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The "Start" message gets printed, but other messages from `searchViaAjax()` don't. And controller method doesn't start.

Comment: can you post your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `id` in controller as it is no issue in your 'id', and also you can skip value attribute in `@RequestParam`.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult")
    public String getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestParam("id") integer id) {
        System.out.println("come to ajax"+ id);
        return "hello";
    }
```

Specify the methodType

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult", methodType=RequestMethod.POST)
```

It is also a good practice to use wrapper instead of primitive

```
@RequestParam("tempId") Integer id
```

the problem is in your ajax `url` attribute.

It should be `url : "./search/api/getSearchResult",`

**Root Cause**:

When you are about to hit your controller, it construct the url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/search/api/getSearchResult
```

and hence such resource is not available and it causes 404 not found error.

In actual the url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/contextroot/search/api/getSearchResult
```

here `contextroot` refers your project name.

Now if you hit url `./search/api/getSearchResult` then `./` refers the base url i,e `localhost:8080/contextroot` and the entire url will be constructed properly.

I would like to recommend you to create global variable in JavaScript say `baseUri` and assign`./` into it.

```
<script>
var baseUri="./";
</script>
```

In your AJAX it becomes

```
url : baseUri+"search/api/getSearchResult",
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Same result. Only "Start" alert

Comment: Same again. And another question. What if I finally get it right and send the value in the controller? I should mark controller method as void and return nothing, so the page won't refresh?

Comment: Okay got it your problem, see my entire edits and execute the same

Comment: I created a new project without spring security and db connection. Still doesn't work (I edited the code above. Is there still something wrong?). Should I even send the data to controller or it would be better to send the data right into db?

Comment: Same result again. I discovered this: https://www.chillyfacts.com/java-jsp-javascript-submit-form-without-reloading-page/ It tells that I can create a new DB connection right in my jsp page and send data through it. But is it ok to use that in my case?

Comment: Do one thing, open browser inspector by right clicking inspect element and then open network, hit the controller again and see the network activity there or attach the snapshot of the same

Answer (score 0):

The code from [user9634982](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9634982/user9634982) was fine, thanks to him. The problem was because I was using slim jQuery version so my browser was giving me "$.ajax is not a function" error. And I didn't see it for hours because I didn't know where to look :facepalm: Thanks again to [user9634982](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9634982/user9634982) for discovering browser inspector to me :D After replacing slim version to usual it still didn't work because of spring security. I added _csrf token and all worked fine. 
.jsp:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

<script>
        function searchViaAjax(id) {
            var csrfHeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
            var csrfTokenValue;

            var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
            for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
                var metaTagName = metaTags[i].getAttribute("name");
                if(metaTagName === "_csrf_header")
                    csrfHeaderName = metaTags[i].getAttribute("content");
                if(metaTagName === "_csrf")
                    csrfTokenValue = metaTags[i].getAttribute("content");
            }

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "./addAnsweredQuestion",
                data : {id:id},
                timeout : 100000,
                beforeSend:function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeaderName, csrfTokenValue);},
                success : function(id) {
                    alert("success");
                    console.log("SUCCESS: ", id);
                    display(id);
                    alert(response);
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert("error");
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                    display(e);
                },
                done : function(e) {
                    alert("done");
                    console.log("DONE");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/addAnsweredQuestion")
    public void getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        System.out.println("come to ajax"+ id);
    }
```